# $SU(N)$ contribution to the gluon propagator

Tags: group-theory, yang-mills, propagator

This is a simple question arisen with the evaluation of the gluon propagator in the Landau gauge for $SU(N)$ Yang-Mills theory. I have to evaluate the integral
$$
\int d^4xe^{ipx}\langle T^cA^c_\mu(x),T^dA^d_\nu(0)\rangle,
$$
being $T_c$ the generators of the group, that we know has the form
$$
G\left(\eta_{\mu\nu}-\frac{p_\mu p_\nu}{p^2}\right)\Delta(x,0)
$$
being $G$ the contribution due to the $SU(N)$ group in the fundamental representation. One assumes that the propagator $\Delta(x,0)$ is given (maybe). Now, my guess for $G$ is
$$
  G=\frac{N^2-1}{2N}.
$$
Is this correct?

Comment: You should be able to evaluate the propagator in perturbation theory. The tree level contribution should be trivial to evaluate. You can use it to derive $G$, provided this factor does not depend on the coupling constant (does it?).

Comment: I thought this was textbook matter. I agree with you that the propagator is known through perturbation theory. This is tree level and I guess no contribution from coupling is seen at this order.

Comment: G should come from T, so why you mention fundamental reps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It kind of depends on what you mean by $T^c$. Let these matrices live in a representation $R$ of the gauge algebra.

Due to $\mathrm{SU}(N)$ invariance, we have
$$
\langle A^a A^b\rangle\propto \delta^{ab}
$$
and therefore the colour structure $G$ is given by
$$
G=T^aT^a\equiv C(R)\times \text{identity matrix}
$$
as per Casimir.

If $R$ is the fundamental representation, we have $C(F)=\frac{N^2-1}{2N}$. If $R$ is the adjoint representation, $C(A)=N$.

Comment: So, are you confirming that my conclusion is right?

Comment: @Jon Yes. But only if $T^a$ live in the fundamental representation (as you say in the OP). In other representations, $G$ changes (it is representation-dependent).